# Convert len() to a string value within a string concatenation expression

Tags: python-3.x

How do I convert the `len()` value to be a string to successfully print the a string expression?

```
vacation = ['Rick', 'Paris', 'Tom', 'James']

print("I live with " + len(vacation) + " people")
```

I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 1, in <module>
   print("I live with " + len(vacation) + " people")
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: All those answers have you converting the string to an int. Don't bother. If you are using Python 3.6 or above, your second line can use an f-string, like this: `print(f'I live with {len(vacation)} people')`. Of course, if you cannot use 3.6 for some reason, the answers below are fine.

Answer (score 1):

use str function to convert int to string:

```
print("I live with " + str(len(vacation)) + " people")
```

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like these, the use of formatting strings is
far more convenient that joining small pieces together with `+`

```
vacation = ['Rick', 'Paris', 'Tom', 'James']
print("I live with %d people" % len(vacation))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
print("I live with %s people" % len(vacation))
```

or

```
print('I live with {} people'.format(len(vacation)))
```

`%s` and `{}` are placeholders for the argument passed.

Comment: I am not familiar with the % sign in this scenario. I will look more into this one. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Use str function.

vacation = ['Rick', 'Paris', 'Tom', 'James']

print("I live with " + str(len(vacation)) + " people")

Comment: This is what I was trying to do initially, I know see that the str portion goes on the outside. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
vacation = ['Rick', 'Paris', 'Tom', 'James']

print(f"I live with {len(vacation)} people")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html for more info.